# Difference between erga and quoad?

Tags: medieval-latin, word-comparison, conjunction, differences

In medieval Latin, is there a difference between [*erga*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?la=la&l=erga#lexicon) and [*quoad*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?la=la&l=quoad#lexicon)? They both seem to mean "with respect to".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*quoad* is only an adverb when it means 'as long as'. When, like *ergā,* it governs a **noun in the accusative,** both are prepositions, but they have different meanings.

***quoad* limits** the application of some assertion or introduces the topic for a following assertion. It's composed of the directional *quō* 'where to' and *ad,* which designates a limit.

- It's only an adverb when it designates a limit in **time** and translates to 'as long as (not), until', as in your last example (*quoad eijus vīta terminētur*); or, with *licēre* and *posse,* a limit of **ability,** 'as far as, as much as'. These are its most common uses.
- In your Aquinas excerpt it's a preposition whose function is likewise limiting or specifying: there are three elements of Sin, and Extreme Unction is said not to remit any of them: 'Sin limited to Stain without Contrition, Sin limited to Punishment, or Sin limited to its Remnants.' It can be understood as a reverse genitive: 'sin as far as its stain => **sin its stain** => the stain of sin'. This construction [is actually grammatical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/His_genitive) in some varieties of English.
- Its other major use as a preposition is disjunctive: *quoad hoc quod compertum est, dīcit...* 'as regards what has been uncovered, he says that...'. Here it establishes (when preceding) or circumscribes (when following) the **topic of discourse.**
- These latter two uses don't depend on any verb and are characteristic of late and especially medieval Latin. Classical Latin uses ***quod ad** X (attinet),* ***quantum ad** X (pertinet)* and especially ***dē*** for the topic-limiting disjunct, and the specifying meaning would be expressed using genitives, adjectives or a relative clause.

***ergā*** has a totally different meaning and expresses the object, and especially the person, whom a (usually good rather than bad) **attidude** or a state-like action is **directed towards:** *nihil ergā eōs agere* 'to do nothing in relation to them', *amor ergā parentēs* 'love towards one's parents'. It has no adverbial or disjunctive uses, but is a pure preposition that depends on some (de-)verbal part of speech, similar to *in* and antonymous to *contrā,* with *adversus* somewhere in the middle.

I can't think of instances where the two are interchangeable.

Answer (score 1):

*Erga* is a preposition; *quoad* is an adverb.

Roy J. DeFerrari, [*A Lexicon of St. Thomas Aquinas*](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=2847), p. 370:

> **ergā**, *prep.* with *acc.*, in general of every kind of mental relation to a person or thing, *to, towards, in respect to*.
>
> > Eliguntur homines ad aliqua officia vel secularia vel ecclesiastica; ab his qui nihil **erga** eos agunt*, [PS. Q. 13. Art. 4](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/FS/FS013.html#FSQ13A4THEP1) ob. 3 […]

<sup>*[Freddoso transl.](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=7724) PDF p. 1036: "Men are chosen to certain offices, whether secular or ecclesiastical, by those who do nothing **with respect to** them."
[Alt. transl.](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/FS/FS013.html#FSQ13A4THEP1): "men are chosen for certain posts, whether secular or ecclesiastical, by those who exercise no action **in their regard** [or '**regarding them**']."</sup>

p. 932:

> **quoad**, *adv.*, (1) *with respect to, as to* = quod attinet ad (with the *acc.* only, in the [S.T.](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/index.html)), (2) *till, until*.
>
> > (1), sed per extrema unctionem non remittitur peccatum **quoad** maculam sine contri­tione, quae etiam sine unctione remittit; nec iterum **quoad** poe­nam, quia adhuc si convalescat, tenetur perficere satisfactionem iniunctam; nec **quoad** reliquias culpae, (ob. 2) […] [PTS. Q. 30. Art. 1](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/XP/XP030.html#XPQ30A1THEP1)
>
> […]
>
> > (2), et similiter de homine aliquo iudicium perfecti dari non potest, **quoad** eius vita terminetur, eo quod multiplicia potest mutari de bono in malum, aut e converso, [PT. Q. 59. Art. 5](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/TP/TP059.html#TPQ59A5THEP1) c.